# Google Cloud SSH won't connect

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh

it seems I've run though everything and it will not connect,
I've verified my firewall is not blocking anything, I reset my ssh keys, I've set my user roles, and I've tried resolving it through the cloud shell.

Code: 4003
Reason: failed to connect to backend
You may be able to connect without using the Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy.

Anyone have any ideas? I just need this to work.

vm instance- OpenLiteSpeed Wordpress
zone- us-east4-b
machine type- n1-standard-1
cpu platform- Intel Broadwell

Answer (score 0):

It seems you already tried to troubleshoot issue , I had similar issue so just want to know below

1. what is your role in project ( owner/editor)?
2. VM instance having external ip or not?

If firewall blocking it will give timeout error, its not timeout error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do not post an answer to ask questions. Post a comment to the question. Delete this post as it is not an answer.

Comment: 1) I am the project owner. 2) the VM has an external static IP address.